# How to determine what compiler does with a metaprogram? (for boost.proto)

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, boost-proto

How do I determine what my compiler (g++) is doing with template code?

I am using boost.proto (an expression-template library) to evaluate some maths expressions at compile time.  The code evaluates the expressions correctly, but I would like to see whether the compiler has expanded out the expression to the equivalent of hand-written c-code (i.e. eliminated all the temporaries), or whether there is still some further compile-time optimizations to be done.

Is there a way to see what the compiler has done with the templates?

Thanks

Comment: You can look at the assembly and compare it to the assembly of had-written C-code.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y is there anything in between my code and assembly - I have never looked at assembly before and find this prospect a bit daunting?

Comment: @Tom: Nothing that I am aware of.

Comment: @Tom: No, there is no intermediate step. There is `g++ -E` to see what the preprocessor does, but templates are up to the compiler, and once the compiler is done, you got assembly...

Comment: You can get g++ to output the code after preprocessing with the flag -E but I dont know if the preprocessor will replace the templates for you.

Comment: @Nobody, I think the template unwinding is done after the preprocessor

Comment: @Tom, there is a plenty of passes in between your source code and assembly. See all that `-fdump-...` options.

Comment: @SK-logic: I doubt that RTL representations of your code are any easier to comprehend than ASM...

Comment: @DevSolar, of course they are easier. Take a look at the `original` pass, for example - it is almost a pure C.

Comment: @Tom, another option for you: Elsa (oink) can dump a readable AST after a type propagation and templates instantiation pass.

Comment: @SK-logic Thanks I found the fdump useful, if you put your comment in an answer I will accept it (I was looking for an indication of what the compiler was doing and the fdump gives it to me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to see a C++ code after the templates instantiation pass:

- Use `gcc -fdump-tree-original` (or even `-fdump-tree-all` to see more passes)
- Use Elsa C++ parser: http://scottmcpeak.com/elkhound/sources/elsa/
- Use Clang and an LLVM C backend - the latter will give the most unreadable code, but it is still useful in some cases. There should be some AST dumping functionality in Clang itself as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
g++ -S
```

is documented as "Compile only; do not assemble or link". Basically you get assembly output.

Comment: oh, I was hoping g++ went to c and then went to assembly.  I have never looked at assembly before, maybe I need to learn...

Comment: @Tom There are a few rare C++ compilers which are really front-ends that emit C code which is in turn compiled; CFront, the very first C++ compiler, worked this way. But outside of Comeau and Edison, no one has done it that way for decades. G++ and MSVC compile directly from C++ to object code.

Comment: @Tom, you may also want to consider compiling your code with Clang instead of Gcc - it is much easier to inspect LLVM IR than an assembly and intermediate GCC representations. You can even produce a plain C code out of it, with LLVM CBE target.

Comment: @Tom: ...but none of these will really tell you how the *other* compiler does it, because how a compiler turns template source code into machine code is very much compiler-specific. So, to paraphrase Donald Knuth, don't bother with optimizations until you *know* you have a performance problem. 98% of the time, it simply *does not matter* if a piece of code works at maximum efficiency.

Comment: @DevSolar, template instantiation process is strictly defined by C++ standard.

Comment: @DevSolar, thats true, but in this case I am calling my expression 10-50 million times.  Also, I am curios as to whether I am using proto library correctly (I want to show off to my friends...)